# Ajax and output pdf file are not working together

Tags: ajax, pdf

I have a file named download.php and call getpdf function inside it.

I call download.php via ajax to download pdf file when users click download button. but nothing happend and no download window appears. I checked it in firebug Net tab and download.php are requested on click event. Its size also changes that shows the file is reading from its location,but no download window.

Here's getpdf code:

```
function getpdf($id) {
  header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
  readfile('/san/theo-books/PDFs/'.$id.'.pdf');
  exit;
}
```

And here's download.php code:

```
$pdf_id = $_POST('pdi');
echo getpdf($pdf_id);
```

What is the problem? Would you help me?

Comment: That's the expected behavior. Your file will be available in the internal methods of your Ajax library. Popup download window needs the full postback.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full postback version. It's not using the jQuery Ajax, because Popup download window needs the full postback:

```
<a id="pdf-10" href="#">PDF Export</a>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[id^="pdf"]').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var pdfExportPath = "/san/theo-books/PDFs/";  
        var $a = $(this);
        var postId = $a.attr('id').replace("pdf-","");
        var form = $('<form action="' + pdfExportPath + '" name="pdf' + postId + '" id="pdf' + postId + '" method="POST"> <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="' + postId + '" /></form>');
        $(form).appendTo('body');
        form.submit();
    });
});
```